# Recursive python function that checks if a string represents the" relief of a landscape"

Tags: python, string, list, function, recursion

I'm trying to build a recursive function to represent the relief of a landscape using a string. The string can have a random length but only contains '\'  '/'  '_'  '¯'.  For example:

> If I give (*/¯\/\__/¯¯\*/\_/\__) it should return True. If the string is empty, it's also valid. It's not valid if there's a discontinuity between consecutive characters, for example, ¯\¯\ or *¯* is not valid.

Examples:

print(isLandscape(' ')) -------- True

print(isLandscape('_')) -------- True

print(isLandscape('_/\_')) -------- True

print(isLandscape('*/¯\/\*__/\_/¯\_')) -------- True

print(isLandscape('_/_/¯_/¯¯')) -------- False

print(isLandscape('_/¯\_\_')) -------- False

I tried to build it with a buch of if statments. It worked, but it was chunky and not recursive. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What was your implementation?  Have you tried it recursively yet?  Why do you think it needs to be recursive if you can accomplish it without recursion?

Comment: I'm struggling a little to understand precisely what the logic of your function is - can you give a few more examples of what it means for a string to "represent a landscape", and what it means when a string does not? thanks

Comment: WHY do you want a recursive function?  This is clearly a simple iterative problem.  `_` can be followed by `/` or `_`.  `/` can only be followed by `¯`, and so on.  One simple loop.

Comment: The idea is to make it look like the relief of a landscape (mountains, valleys, plateaus)

Comment: I'm currently learning python and I'm trying to solve an exercise that requires the function to be recursive

Answer (score 0):

You want a datastructure like this:

```
level = {
    "_": (0, 0),  # initial level, final level
    "¯": (1, 1),
    "/": (0, 1),
    r"\": (1, 0),
}
```

Now it's just a matter of iterating through
characters and looking up the levels.
Verify that final level of character `i`
is identical to initial level of character `i + 1`.